# how do jquery adresses failed ajax requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I have a piece of code:

```
$.get("go.php?action=sliderorder&right=5")
.success(function(data){alert("success!");})
.fail(function(data){alert("failed!");});
```

The output of the ajax call is "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near..."

The alert i'm getting is still "success!" although clearly the ajax failed.
So my question is: how do jquery address failed ajax calls?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Check your backend code in `go.php`. What are you returning when an exception is thrown? Do you ever return a failure?

Comment: I take this as a failure, when MySQL returns an error

Comment: "The alert i'm getting is still "success!" although clearly the ajax failed." I mean returning a 5xx HTTP status code when I say "return a failure". @zerkms 's got you covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It determines if the error occurred by [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). The 4xx and 5xx codes is what you're after.

But, you generally should **NEVER** get "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds " error. Without exceptions - this should **NEVER** occur in your production code. If it does - you immediately should find the roots of the issue.

Comment: Ok that's a start, is there a way for PHP to tell the page it failed in doing what it should have been doing? such as "die()"?

Comment: Is there a way to combine with an "mysql_query("") or die()" ?

Comment: @Nir Tzezana: `$result = mysql_query(...); if (!$result) {}`. But normally your `mysql_query` shouldn't fail, at least with syntactic error reason. I would say you need to fix your code, because it looks like it's broken